# T-SQL 2014 XQuery solution to using substring

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

I'm trying to write an update statement to an XML column in a table that is formatted like this.

this is in on field of of a table

```
 <Params>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>Bar</LastName>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Pam</FirstName>
            <LastName>Foo</LastName>
        </Account>
    </Params>




**this is in on field of ONE of another record in that table
    <Params>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Darold</FirstName>
            <LastName>ok</LastName>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
            <LastName>whatever</LastName>
        </Account>
        <Account>
             <FirstName>amy</FirstName>
             <LastName>whatever</LastName>
    </Account>
    </Params>
**
```

Desired output

```
    <Params>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Michael2334</FirstName>
            <LastName>Bar2334</LastName>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Pam2334</FirstName>
            <LastName>Foo2334</LastName>
        </Account>
    </Params>





    <Params>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Darold2335</FirstName>
            <LastName>ok2335</LastName>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>Fred2335</FirstName>
            <LastName>whatever2335</LastName>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <FirstName>amy2335</FirstName>
            <LastName>whatever2335</LastName>
        </Account>
    </Params>
```

My ultimate objective is to update the entire table's xml field, which has nth amount of nodes with a joined tables ID column, and append that ID to the First and Last Name

the "specs" are to update the first name and put the id (integer) column at the end of the last name and first name (which i have solved in a PoC from the SQLFiddle below, but not fully as it only works if there is one record in the table, and only tried firstname for now)

**I SPENT ALL DAY**

I have looked over the internet and the function modify(replace value of...) can only effect 1 of the accounts at a time.  Because of this, I had to create a loop like so.  But its very ugly and the bottom variable KeepGoing would have worked so much better if SQL Server would support the XPath function `matches()` and could check for the existence of a digit with **regular expressions** but this is not in SQL Server 2017. My work around is going to use `contains()` 10 times! To see if I'm done and can move on to the next record.

If anyone has a better elegant solution please let me know. The person who is requesting this wants this is all one statement and no cursors. Which I already from the code below have gone of course and given up.

1) What would be the query to return from the below XML that would return

```
4
4
```

`4` for the last character in FirstName

and

`4` for the last character in FirstName in the second node

this select should also return

5

5

for the next record

But this is not the MAIN problem, this is a fyi trying to use substring and in xpath

im trying to evaluate via a while loop so i know when to stop executing on [1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7eed1)
by looking for an integer on the last character, i have failed trying to write below

SELECT 
    XMLCol.value('//Account/FirstName/text()[substring(., string-length(x)-1,11)]', 'nvarchar(255)) 
FROM
    XMLtbl

I have been trying all formations of below only to get this messages like...

> Msg 2203, Level 16, State 1, Line 114
>   XQuery [XMLtbl.XMLCol.value()]: Only 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal?', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean?' or 'node()*' expressions allowed as predicates, found 'xs:string'

Here is everything I'm working on

this is a little bit less then making SQL string and dynamically running the SQL using `EXEC`, just trying to do it the best way possible.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7eed1

Much obliged I knew xquery/xpath was nothing easy, and stayed away from it and left it for the experts

The Final fiddle (based on answer below, but it has a few more fields that i use that are irrelevant to the question)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afff6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite long, almost *TL;DR*, but still not very clear... It would help to provide the expected output...

Some asumptions and statements:

- Yes, `.modify()` allows for one single change per call - quite a limitation...
- You want to update your XML on several places
- From your *specs* you want to add the ID into the XML
- Don't know what you want to achieve with the *last letter approach*

However, in your case it seems best to shred the XML and re-create it from scratch. You can use any `T-SQL` functionality for this:

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<Params>
    <Account>
        <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
        <LastName>Bar</LastName>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <FirstName>Pam</FirstName>
        <LastName>Foo</LastName>
    </Account>
</Params>')
,(N'<Params>
    <Account>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Wood</LastName>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
        <LastName>Stone</LastName>
    </Account>
</Params>');
```

-- The query uses an "updateable CTE" to create the value, which can be used in the UPDATE afterwards.

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.YourXML
          ,(
            SELECT 
                  --just silly, to show how it works: append "blah" to the first name
                   Acc.value(N'(FirstName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') + '_blah' AS FirstName
                   --Just pick the last character as LastName
                  ,RIGHT(Acc.value(N'(LastName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1) AS LastName
                  --Add the ID in the last place
                  ,t2.ID
            FROM @tbl AS t2
            CROSS APPLY t2.YourXML.nodes(N'/Params/Account') AS A(Acc)
            WHERE t2.ID=t.ID
            FOR XML PATH('Account'),ROOT('Params'),TYPE
           ) AS NewXML
    FROM @tbl AS t
)
UPDATE cte SET YourXML=NewXML;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

One of these XMLs would look like this after the action

```
<Params>
  <Account>
    <FirstName>Michael_blah</FirstName>
    <LastName>r</LastName>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <FirstName>Pam_blah</FirstName>
    <LastName>o</LastName>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </Account>
</Params>
```

### UPDATE

This query will append the row's ID (padded to a five-digit number) to both name parts:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.YourXML
          ,(
            SELECT 
                   Acc.value(N'(FirstName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') + REPLACE(STR(t2.ID,5),' ','0') AS FirstName
                  ,Acc.value(N'(LastName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') + REPLACE(STR(t2.ID,5),' ','0') AS LastName
            FROM @tbl AS t2
            CROSS APPLY t2.YourXML.nodes(N'/Params/Account') AS A(Acc)
            WHERE t2.ID=t.ID
            FOR XML PATH('Account'),ROOT('Params'),TYPE
           ) AS NewXML
    FROM @tbl AS t
)
UPDATE cte SET YourXML=NewXML;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

And this query will deliver the last character of each name

```
SELECT Acc.value(N'substring((FirstName/text())[1],string-length((FirstName/text())[1]),1)',N'char(1)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXML.nodes(N'/Params/Account') AS A(Acc);
```

Comment: the ID being added is not a requirement sorry about the long message, but this gives me some ammo and will try, actually the ID is being added where you put _blah

Comment: so imagine michael_23656, i need to keep running the statement until the an exist statment returns false one a condition checking for a number as the last character or regexp of digits in the string

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik provide some realistic (but reduced!) input and the output you'd expect after the action. This helps more, than hundred lines of prosa...

Comment: will do , give me a moment

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Your comment might be clear for you, but I'm not sitting at your side, I don't know what's in your mind - sorry, I have no idea, what you need... Use the edit option of your question to add input and output...

Comment: i edited the answer a little bit.  FYI that xml that is a field in a record was an example of just one row.   The number thats beeing appended to the end is actually the ID column to the name(not a new xml element/node).  I have many rows to update.  Hopefully your TSQL solved that, if not i will still need a loop of some kind but maybe i will not have to depend on xpath anymore from you answer.  But still am interested in how to execute a substring with substring-length - 1, to get the last byte, but thats not whats important.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Is there a reason, that in your edits the ID is not appended to each and any LastName, any logic behind this?

Comment: ok i think the spec is done.  Understand the real objective is to just update the xml field in the table (which could have n amount of nodes), and each name field needs to have a joined tables id column appended to it.

The reason i brought up the last digit thing, is at least my working solution, if i detect the last digit is not a number, i know i have to keep executing the statement in a loop.  if it IS a number, i can work on the NEXT ID

Comment: no thats just a typo. It should be for each lastname and each firstname (i will edit)  But when i had at this working somewhat, i couldnt have an update that set to modifiy statements in the same clause

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik about your *no thats just a typo*. For your next question: Please be very careful with what you post. People like me try to understand the logic behind and *just a typo* is a bit annoying ...